# logstash multi pipeline decider

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Following is my use case,
Based on some business logic at run time, i need to publish events generated from log file to different elastic search endpoints.
Input plugin (file name) will be same, but output plugin (elastic endpoint) may change. I cannot feed this data generated at run time in each log line. 
For eg, thread1 and thread2 are both generating logs to app.log. I want to push logs from thread1 to elastic endpoint1 and logs from thread2 to elastic endpoint2. In this case input ( app.log ) is same for both.
Is this achievable ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use `if` conditions in your output.

You will need to have a field to filter, for example a field named `thread` which will have the value of the thread, `thread1` or `thread2`, then you need something like this:

```
output {
    if [thread] == "thread1" {
        elasticsearch to endpoint1
    }
    if [thread] == "thread2" {
        elasticsearch to endpoint2
    }
}
```